# Where can I find comscore rank?

Tags: analytics, traffic

Recently one ad network rejected my registration stating that my site doesn't match their minimum monthly impressions, even though the site serves thrice the required page views. When I contacted them for details, their representative hinted that they are using comscore data for screening submissions.

Where can I view my site's comscore ranking and details?

**Update** I was able to find the traffic by tagging my site with [comScore Direct](http://direct.comscore.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably from [Comscore](http://www.comscore.com/) directly although I suspect you'll have to pay for the information.